# Does everyone see the same "Hot Network Questions"?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

Hot Network Questions are wonderful to discover things one never expected to read about.

I was always wondering whether the list seen on the side bar, or the one at https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot are the same for every Stack Exchange visitor, or whether they are filtered based on some criteria? (logged in or not, most active networks for the user, previous visits to a SE site from HNQ, ...)

Comment: I don't even see the same HNQ from stack to stack, or on two successive visits to the same stack within 10 minutes...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: they seem to come from a pool, I was wondering how this pool is filtered (specifically - whether it is filtered based on the watching user behaviour/profile)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that list is cached for at least 5 minutes and in that time the same HNQ list is delivered to everyone. There are way more then 100 questions hot at any given time. On each page load users get a random subset of 25 hot questions. See also [the status page I have available in my HNQ chat feed app](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/status) and this SEDE query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1293884/all-hot-questions-networkwide-for-a-given-date?hotdate=2020-08-31

Comment: They don't see the same, no.